# JMS DI Extra Bundle: How do I inject a dependency only if it exists

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I am using JMS DI to inject services with annotation:

```
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;
/**
 * @DI\Service("foo.bar.service")
 */
class myClass
{
    /**
    * @DI\Inject("debug.stopwatch")
    * @var $stopWatch \Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Stopwatch
    */
    public $stopWatch;

    /**
    * @DI\Inject("serializer")
    * @var $serializer \JMS\Serializer\Serializer
    */
    public $serializer;

    public function toto()
    {
       if (isset($this->stopwatch)) {
         $this->stopWatch->start("init");
       }
    }
}
```

But StopWatch is only available in Dev Env, so when running in prod:

```
The service "foo.bar.service" has a dependency on a non-existent service "debug.stopwatch".' in...
```

My question: **How can i inject the stopwatch service properly in my class ?**

Comment: sometimes you need to read the doc [one more time](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/annotations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the dependency [optional](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html#making-references-optional):

```
@DI\Inject("debug.stopwatch", required=false)
```

Comment: perfect, re-read the doc and [found it](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/annotations), thx.